# PyQt5 QCheckbox with image

Tags: python, image, pyqt5, qcheckbox

Is there a way to implement checkbox with image? I want to create side bar with the list of checkbox with images, like i did it here with html, css and js:

[image: list of checkbox]

The style is not important, first of all I want to know how to make the functionality. Thanks in advance!

Update #2

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

layout = QVBoxLayout()

frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
frame.setLayout(layout)
layout.addWidget(frame)

cb = QCheckBox('Yes', frame)
layout.addWidget(cb)

lb = QLabel("Do you like programming?", cb)
lb.setPixmap(QPixmap("26.png"))
layout.addWidget(lb)

window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Use a container widget (or even just a layout) with an empty checkbox and a QLabel with its pixmap set.

Comment: Something like this (added to my post)? But checkbox doesnt check when you click on the image

Comment: Subclass the label and override the mousePressEvent handler, or install an event filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all came to this solution:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
import os
icon_path = os.getcwd() + r"\26.png"

class QDMQListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        if self.currentItem().checkState() == Qt.Checked:
            self.currentItem().setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        elif self.currentItem().checkState() == Qt.Unchecked:
            self.currentItem().setCheckState(Qt.Checked)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    lw = QDMQListWidget()
    for i in range(5):
        text = f'{i}'
        icon = QtGui.QIcon(icon_path)
        item = QListWidgetItem(icon, text)
        item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        lw.addItem(item)
    lw.setDragDropMode(lw.InternalMove)
    lw.setIconSize(QSize(400, 400))
    lw.setSelectionMode(True)
    lw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```